# NFC no obligatoria para app en google play

Tags: android, nfc

Tengo una aplicación que puede o no trabajar con `NFC`. He añadido estas líneas al `manifest`:

```
<manifest>..
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" 
android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
</manifest>
```

Cuando busco la aplicación en Google Play sigue saliendo el mensaje: "Tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta versión"

He comprobado que el `NFCAdapter` no sea nulo, he solicitado los permisos pertinentes directamente en ejecución.. pero sigue saliendo ese mensaje.

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.app.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".timer.UploadService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".services.uploaddata.ui.UploadDataService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".main.ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".p1.ui.class1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_class1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".p2.ui.class2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_class2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/class2ActivityTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".p3.ui.class3"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_class3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".p4.ui.class4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_class4"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".p5.ui.class5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_class5"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: El filtrado de tu dispositivo en Google Play no depende únicamente de NFC, te recomiendo agregar tu AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @Jorgesys manifest incluido :)

Comment: Gracias ahora si es más claro que sucede, agregué respuesta m saludos @ClaraPeña

Comment: Problema solucionado. Sólo tenía que esperar a que Google actualizase sus servidores, cosa que ha tardado entre uno y dos días.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque definiste como no requerido el hardware para el uso de NFC en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
```

este no determina la razón por la cual tu disposivo sea filtrado desde Google PlayStore.

De hecho veo otras caracteristicas que pueden estar filtrando tu dispositivo o los de otros usuarios, modificalas agregando  `android:required="false"` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"/>
```

Sube una actualización y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación. Pero desafortunadamente el gran fallo que tengo es la impaciencia. Solo tenía que esperar el tiempo suficiente (de 1 a 2 días) para que Google actualizase sus servidores. Muchas gracias igualmente :)